# Find the solution of the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=x^2y$ satisfying $y(0)=5$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm not entirely sure I'm on the right track, and my teacher seemed to fly through this section, so I don't really understand *what* I'm doing.

Anyway, here is the problem again:

Find the solution of the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=x^2y$ satisfying $y(0)=5$

By rote I know to do the following...

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=x^2y$$
$$\int\frac{dy}{y}=\int x^2dx$$
$$ln|y|=\frac{x^3}{3}+C$$

So then using the initial value condition...

$$ln|5|=\frac{(0)^3}{3}+C$$

So $C=ln|5|$  Next I used this value for $C$ to solve for y:

$$ln|y|=\frac{x^3}{3}+ln|5|$$
$$ln|y|=\frac{x^3+ln|5|}{3}$$
$$|y|=e^\frac{x^3+ln|5|}{3}$$

So I got here and wasn't sure if it were right and didn't know what to do with the absolute values.  Am I on the right track?

Comment: It is correct. See the RHS of the last equation is always positive , so you may take y instead of |y|.

Comment: $5$ is positive so no need for $|5|$, exponential is positive so no need for $|y|$...I forgot to say.... Well done :)

Comment: Careful, $\dfrac{x^3}{3}+\ln5=\dfrac{x^3+3\ln5}{3}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\ln|y|={x^3\over 3}+\ln 5\implies e^{\ln|y|}=e^{{x^3\over 3}+\ln 5}\implies |y|=e^{x^3/3}e^{\ln 5}\implies y=5e^{x^3/3}$

The last step holds since $e^{x^3/3}e^{\ln 5}>0$.

(Note that you have an algebra error in your next to last displayed equation.)

Comment: why $y=5e^{\frac{x^3}{3}}$ only,what about $y=-5e^{\frac{x^3}{3}}$.$$5e^{\frac{x^3}{3}}\geq 0$$ doesn't imply that only first solution is valid. $y=-5e^{\frac{x^3}{3}}$ is also satisfy above differential equation and hence also a solutin for it.

Comment: Oh,I got it.wetake only +ve solution because of initial condition is +ve.right?

Comment: @JibinJoyK: That is correct.